# Cart Price Rules having issues

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.2

So I created a rule with these conditions:

[image]

Everything is working fine except for the State/Province conditions. It seems the rule is not taking the conditions for the state/province section. My rule is only to be applied for customers in the U.S. but not Hawaii or Alaska. But since it is not working correctly the rule is applying to these countries.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have just create a rule with condition you specified in question and it is working fine at my end. I have just skip `Shipping Country is not Canada`

Comment: @pawan the problem is not the rule as all my conditions are correct. Something is happening that the rules are not taking into account the state/province conditions

Comment: can you attach detailed screenshots of your cart price rule ? I just created a rule with same conditions and it is working fine for me

Comment: @DevAnd I have wrote my answer and I also attached some screenshots

Comment: Adding superfluous information to the rule isn't needed. Unless you list all Canadian Provences, you should remove Canada from the list. It would also be of easier to see what you're trying to accomplish with the full rule, priority, and other rules which may cause conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a rule with same conditions as yours and it is working fine.
Refer below screenshots:

[image]

Here check screenshots of my cart as well:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyPVp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oG78.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UUhp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/muIvm.png